# In which cases is it unsafe to (const) reference a return value?

Tags: c++

I tend do use the following notation a lot:

```
const Datum& d = a.calc();
// continue to use d
```

This works when the result of calc is on the stack, see http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/. Even though compilers probably optimize here, it feels nice to explicitly avoid temporary objects.

Today I realized, that the content of `d` became invalid after data was written to a member of `a`. In this particular case the get function simply returned a reference to another member, which was completely unrelated to the write however. Like this:

```
const Datum& d = a.get();
// ... some operation ...
a.somedata = Datum2();
// now d is invalid.
```

Again, somedata has nothing to do with `d` or `get()` here.

Now I ask myself:

1. Which side-effects could lead to the invalidation?
2. Is it bad-practice to assign return values to a const reference? (Especially when I don't know the interior of the function)

My application is single-threaded except for a Qt GUI-Thread.

Comment: It depends on what the function returns. Notice in the `GOTW` the function returns by `value` (copy) which becomes a temporary.

Comment: What if the function returns a reference to a member and I know that the member is valid while I use `d`?

Comment: If `somedata` has nothing to do with `get()` I don't understand how assigning to it can invalidate `d`. Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's fine. The function should document what it returns. If it returns a reference then it is the function's job to make sure that reference does not go out of scope when the function returns and that it has a relevant (documented) lifespan. The caller should know how long the reference will remain valid.

Comment: @Chris Drew: Me neither. I tried to set up a mcve, but failed. This is why I am asking. :-/

Comment: @MartinR. Just a wild guess, but are there any containers involved? Adding to some containers can invalidate existing references.

Comment: Chris Drew: No, the variable I am referencing is basically a struct and the other member that is changed is an OpenCV cv::Mat.

Comment: Or more precisely, the referenced has the type `const Eigen::Vector3d&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which side-effects could lead to the invalidation?

Holding a reference to the internal state of a class (i.e., versus extending the lifetime of a temporary) and then calling any non-const member functions may potentially invalidate the reference.

> Is it bad-practice to assign return values to a const reference? (Especially when I don't know the interior of the function)

I would say the *bad practice* is to hold a reference to the internal state of a class instance, mutating the class instance, and continuing to use the original reference (unless it is documented that the non-const functions don't invalidate the reference)

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be afraid of elision failing.  That `auto x = some_func();` will result in an extra move construct over `auto&& x = some_func();` when `some_func()` returns a temporary object.

You shouldn't be.

If elision fails, it means your compiler is incompetent, or compiling with frankly hostile settings.  And you cannot survive hostile settings or incompetent compilers: incompetent compilers can turn `a+=b` with integers into `for (int i = 0; i < abs(b); ++i) {if (b>0) ++a; else --a;}` and violate not one iota of the standard.

Elision is a core language feature.  Don't write bad code just because you don't trust it will happen.

---

You should capture by reference when you want a reference to the data provided by the function, and not an independently stable copy of the data.  If you don't understand the function's return value's lifetime, capturing by reference is simply *not safe*.

Even if you know that the data will be stable, more time is spent maintaining code than writing it: the person reading your code must be able to see at a glance that your assumption holds.  And non-local bugs are bad: a seemingly innocuous change to the function you call should not break your code.

---

The end result is, take things by value unless you have a good reason not to.

Taking things by value makes it easier for you, and the compiler, to reason about your code.  It increases locality.

When you have a good reason not to, then take things by reference.

Depending on context, this good reason might not have to be very strong.  But it shouldn't be based off an assumption of an incompetent compiler.

Premature pessimization should be avoided, but so should premature optimization.  Taking (or storing) references instead of values should be something you do when and if you have identified performance problems.  Write clean, easy to understand code.  Shove complexity into tightly written types, and have the exterior interface be clean and simple.  Take things by value, because values decouple state.

---

Optimization is fungible.  By making more of your code simpler, you can make it easier to work with (and be more productive).  Then, when you identify parts where performance matters, you can expend effort *there* to make the code faster.

A big example is foundational code: foundational code (which is used everywhere) quickly becomes a general drag on performance if not written with performance *and* ease of use in mind.  In that case, you want to hide complexity *inside* the type, and expose a simple easy to use exterior interface that doesn't require the user to understand the guts.

But code in a random function somewhere?  Use values, the easiest to use containers with the friendliest O-notation to the *most expensive* operation you do and the easiest interface.  Vectors if reasonable (avoid premature pessmiziation), but don't sweat a few maps.

Find the 1%-10% of your code that takes up 90%-99% of the time, and make that fast.  If the rest of your code has good O-notation performance (so it won't become shockingly slower with larger data sets than you test with), you'll be in good shape.  Then start testing with ridiculous data-sets, and find the slow parts then.

Comment: @light `std::vector` and the like -- the library or library-esque code that sits below the other code that is widely used.  If it is a bit slow or bulky, it won't show up in a particular slow task as being key, but rather slow down everything marginally.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I am answering exactly what you expected to hear but...
`const` keyword has nothing to do with the 'unsafe' here.
Even if you return non const reference, it may become invalid. `const` means that it is not allowed to modify it. For example if your `get()` returns a const member or `get()` itself is defined as `const` like this `const some_refetence_t& get() const { return m_class_member; }`.
Now regarding your questions at the end:

1. > Which side-effects could lead to the invalidation?

There could be many side effects if the original value changes. For example let's assume that the returned value is a reference to an object on the heap which is deleted... or the returned value is cached while the original value gets updates. All these are design problems. If by design such case can take place then the return value should be by value (and in case of caching, it must not be cached! :) ).

2. > Is it bad-practice to assign return values to a const reference?
   >   (Especially when I don't know the interior of the function)

Same thing. If by design you don't have to modify the object that you get (by reference or by value) than it is the best to define it as `const`. Once you define something as `const`, the compiler will make sure that you are not trying to modify it somehow in the code.

Comment: The question's more about the reference than about the `const` (which just permits the temp-binding). And I'm not sure what sort of caching you had in mind?

Comment: Caching a value => saving localy the result in order not to call the get() any more.

Comment: What does that have to do with the code or the question?

Comment: If you save a value of something that might be changed later it will have an unpleasent sideffect which will make the cached data invalid.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score -1):

It is rather question of knowing what your functions return. You should also have a full understanding of the return value type and it's semantics.